# How was Philip's testimony established in Samaria, Acts 8:5-6?

Tags: acts, mark, deuteronomy, 2-corinthians

Acts 8:5-6 NASB

> Philip went down to the city of Samaria and began proclaiming the [d]Christ to them. 6 The crowds were paying attention with one mind to what was being said by Philip, as they heard and saw the [e]signs which he was performing.

According to Paul in the book of Corinthians two or more witnesses are needed which is also in keeping with the law in Deuteronomy.

2 Corinthians 13:1 NASB

> This is the third time that I am coming to you. On the [a]testimony of two or three witnesses every matter shall be confirmed.

Deuteronomy 19:15 NASB

> “A single witness shall not rise up against a person regarding any wrongdoing or any sin [r]that he commits; on the [s]testimony of two or three witnesses a matter shall be confirmed.

Even when Christ sent his disciples they went out in pairs so as to establish the word

Mark 6:7 NASB

> And He *summoned the twelve and began to send them out in pairs, and gave them authority over the unclean spirits;

Unlike Paul who had many witnesses on his witnessing missionaries, Philip seems to have been alone in most of his missions

How was Philip's testimony established?

Answer (score 1):

If we accept that the canonical writings of the NT were inspired (2 Tim 3:16, 17, 2 Peter 1:19-21, then we have the following possibilities:

- Luke was informed by Philip himself and Luke was also advised by the Holy Spirit thus providing two witnesses
- Luke was informed by Philip and either the some of the other people involved in Philip's activities and/or witnesses to those activities

In any case, Luke does not document his sources and so we cannot know for sure, except that if the Holy Spirit inspired Luke, then such a witness is adequate, at least for myself.